# predicting brushless motor rotation direction?

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor

When connecting a brushless motor to an ESC, we are taught to apply power and switch two of the wires if the blade is spinning in the wrong direction.

Is it possible to predict the blade rotation by examining the ESC and motor?

(note: learning-style question, I don't have a practical problem with switching wires)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've asked this on rcgroups as well, and it seems there's no way other than experimenting.  If you had a similar bunch of motors and speed controllers that were manufactured identically, then it would be possible to experiment with one motor/esc set and apply the discovered rotation to the other motors and controllers.

Answer (score 1):

When starting up a brushless motor will turn in a random direction determined by the position of it's windings and magnets. For an ESC to make it turn for example clockwise, it will apply a pulse of current, read the Back EMF from the windings, and if the BEMF matches the right direction it will continue, if it doesn't match, it will reverse the polarity of the circuit.

Hope this clears it up :)